# How do I hook into a button click event on a custom form?

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to write a Custom Form in Outlook 365 (only interested in desktop Outlook).

I click New Email, Developer Tab, Design this form. I add a new button. The default name is "CommandButton1". I then click "View Code" and put:

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    MsgBox "Hello World"
End Sub
```

I then "Run this form", click the button and... nothing.

How do I hook into the Click Event of this custom button control on a custom Outlook Form?

Comment: I just tried the exact same procedure and can not reproduce the behavior.

Comment: Are you saying it worked for you? You did the above and when you pressed the button it popped up with that message?

Comment: sorry for the late reply. Yes it did, and every time i clicked cb1 it would close and reopen the form. To stop the loop you had to press the close(X) button.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're using the Project's VBA editor.

You must use the button's script editor.

For example:

**1)** Select the button

**2)** Open script editor

**3)** Write your code

[image]